# How to find the n-smallest values per column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 74 columns and 1000 rows. I'd like to find the 20 smallest value(s) per column, calculate the mean of these 20 values and return the result as a transposed dataframe with one column and 74 rows

```
               1               2               3    
A         2013918.153207  2010286.148942  2010903.782339  
B         1694927.195604  1648518.272357  1665890.462014     
C         1548895.121455  1594033.016024  1589820.170989
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: you want [nsmallest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html#pandas.Series.nsmallest) for the first point, everything else should be trivial, could you try this and if unsuccessful post your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) what working with `Series` (columns), so need `apply`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).mean()).to_frame('val'))
            val
1  1.621911e+06
2  1.621276e+06
3  1.627855e+06
```

**Numpy solution**:

First convert to `numpy array`, sort by columns, select rows and get `mean`. Last use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = df.values
arr.sort(axis=0)
print (arr)
[[ 1548895.121455  1594033.016024  1589820.170989]
 [ 1694927.195604  1648518.272357  1665890.462014]
 [ 2013918.153207  2010286.148942  2010903.782339]]

print (np.mean(arr[:2,:], axis=0))
[ 1621911.1585295  1621275.6441905  1627855.3165015]

print (pd.DataFrame({'val':np.mean(arr[:2,:], axis=0)}, index=df.columns))
            val
1  1.621911e+06
2  1.621276e+06
3  1.627855e+06
```